# How to combine values from three columns together in MSSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In MSQL Server we have table "Chickens". Chickens have a unique `cell_code` consisting of `workshop_number`, `row_number` and `cell_number`.

```
Chikens
--------------------
workshop_number int
row_number  int
cell_number int
cell_code
--------------------

workshop_number | row_number | cell_number | cell_code
12              | 14         | 38          | 12-14-38
17              | 27         | 43          |17-27-43
```

`cell_code` should looks like `workshop_number-row_number-cell_code` with any delimiters (like "-") or without them at all, for each row in `Chikens`.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result (all as properly formatted text, not images or links), i.e. a [mcve]. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: BTW, you want a view, or a _computed column_.

Comment: ```workshop_number | row_number | cell_number | cell_code
12                           | 14                 | 38                 |12-14-38
17                           | 27                 | 43                 |17-27-43

```

Comment: `ALTER TABLE Chickens ADD cell_code AS CONCAT_WS('-', workshop_number, row_number, cell_number);`